# Redirigir a dos paginas con javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo esta función:

```
function insert()
{
    var id_cliente = $("#id_clienteVal").val();
    var id_alumno = $("#id_alumnoVal").val();

    if(id_alumno > 0)
    {
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../includes/acciones/reservacion/insert.php",
        data: "id_evento=" + id_evento + "&id_zona=" + id_zona + "&asientos=" + JSON.stringify(asientos)
              + "&id_cliente=" + id_cliente + "&id_alumno=" + id_alumno, 
        success: function(data)
        { 
            if(data > 0)
            {
                vex.dialog.alert({
                  message: "Compra realizada exitosamente!!!!",
                  callback: function (value) {
                  if(value)
                  {
                    window.open('imprimir_recibos.php?var=' + window.btoa(data), '_blank');
                    //window.location.href = "reservacion.php?var=" + window.btoa(id_evento);           
                    window.open("reservacion.php?var=" + window.btoa(id_evento));                   
                  }
                 }
                });
            }
            else
                vex.dialog.alert("No se pudo realizar correctamente la compra");
        }           
     });
    }
    else
        vex.dialog.alert("Por favor ingresa el nombre del alumno(a) para terminar la reservación");
}
```

Como pueden ver trato de hacer dos redirecciones a distintas páginas, aparentemente las hace bien pero cuando quiero volver a interactuar con la pagina reservacion.php no me deja hacer nada, como podría solucionar este error??

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucione cambiando la redirección HTTP en lugar de que se comportara como si se diera click en un enlace.

```
function insert()
{
    var id_cliente = $("#id_clienteVal").val();
    var id_alumno = $("#id_alumnoVal").val();

    if(id_alumno > 0)
    {
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../includes/acciones/reservacion/insert.php",
        data: "id_evento=" + id_evento + "&id_zona=" + id_zona + "&asientos=" + JSON.stringify(asientos)
              + "&id_cliente=" + id_cliente + "&id_alumno=" + id_alumno, 
        success: function(data)
        { 
            if(data > 0)
            {
                vex.dialog.alert({
                  message: "Compra realizada exitosamente!!!!",
                  callback: function (value) {
                  if(value)
                  {
                    window.open('imprimir_recibos.php?var=' + window.btoa(data), '_blank');
                    //window.location.href = "reservacion.php?var=" + window.btoa(id_evento);           
                    window.location.replace("reservacion.php?var=" + window.btoa(id_evento));                   
                  }
                 }
                });
            }
            else
                vex.dialog.alert("No se pudo realizar correctamente la compra");
        }           
     });
    }
    else
        vex.dialog.alert("Por favor ingresa el nombre del alumno(a) para terminar la reservación");
}
```